# Change row opacity in certain conditions

Tags: php, symfony4, sonata-admin

In a sonata admin project, using symfony 4, I would like to change the row opacity based on an entity field called visible, which is a boolean of course.

In other words, if the visible field is true, the opacity is going to be 1, else is going to be 0.2 or something like that.

I have done my research and I have found a couple of articles regarding the customization of the row templates, but none of those articles seems to be usefull to me. I know for a fact this is possible but I cant find the way to do it.

This is my list mapper.

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
      ->addIdentifier('title', null, [
        'label' => 'Titulo',
        'sortable' => false
      ])
      ->add('description', null, [
        'label' => 'Descripcion',
        'sortable' => false
      ])
      ->add('idAuthor.name', null, [
        'label' => 'Autor',
        'sortable' => false
      ])
      ->add('idCategory.name', null, [
        'label' => 'Categoria',
        'sortable' => false
      ])
      ->add('position', null, [
        'label' => 'Posicion',
        'sortable' => false
      ])
      ->add('visible', 'boolean', [
        'label' => 'Visible',
        'editable' => true
      ])
      ->add('_action', null, [
        'label' => 'Ordenar posicion',
        'actions' => [
          'move' => [
            'template' => '@PixSortableBehavior/Default    /_sort_drag_drop.html.twig',
            'enable_top_bottom_buttons' => false
          ],
        ],
      ]);
  }
```

As you can see there is my visible field, which can be edited on the page, i would like to change that row opacity depending on that variable

This is the html twig file where I think I have to code my logic,
base_list_inner_row.html.twig file

```
{% for field_description in admin.list.elements %}
    {% if field_description.name == '_action' and     app.request.isXmlHttpRequest %}
        {# Action buttons disabled in ajax view! #}
    {% elseif field_description.getOption('ajax_hidden') == true and     app.request.isXmlHttpRequest %}
    {% else %}
        {{ object|render_list_element(field_description) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: show us your code. or we can't answer.

Comment: Do all your rendering in PHP, then you just need to output one twig var. Try not to have any logic other than loops and echoes in a view file.

Comment: check for twig extension function `render_list_element`

Comment: Thanks, I could give it a try, I already solve my problem with a different approach tho, I managed to set a default filter, soo , only the visible items show and to see the invisibles ones you gotta change the filter but when you refresh the default filter activates again.